# How to convert Session to var

Tags: c#

Hi How to assign Session to var... Example :
   var kar = Session["CalenderCount"] ;????????

```
var kar = Session["CalenderCount"] ;????????

if(session["CalenderCount"]==null)
{
    var kar = CALLOBJECT(.....);
             Session["CalenderCount"] = kar;
              foreach (var i in kareo)
             {}
}
else
 var kar = Session["CalenderCount"] ;????????
    foreach (var i in kar){}  //   Here Error Comes
```

Comment: Where is `kareo ` initialised?

Comment: You must care of your question formats. I checked your other quiestions and their format are terrible too.

Comment: Thanks for your Comments... I solve it...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "convert" anything to a [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) as it uses implicit typing. So that answers the question.

If you post the error, we can maybe help you a bit more with regards to that.